# RSpec.describe vs describe

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I'm starting a new Rails project for the first time in a while.  When scaffolding a model, Rspec creates describe blocks predicated with "RSpec"

```
RSpec.describe MyModel do
  ...
end
```

vs the old style:

```
describe MyModel do
  ...
end
```

I've perused the change log but must be missing the rational for the change?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

As of RSpec 3 you can disable the global availability of `describe` by limiting the [domain specific language (dsl)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain-specific_language).

Prefixing with `RSpec.describe` ensures tests will still run after implementing the limitation.

Note: you still don't need the prefix, unless you turn off the availability with `config.expose_dsl_globally = false`

**Edit:** link to dsl wikipedia

Answer (score 34):

Via the commit:

> In a concerted effort to keep monkey patching to a minimum. The
>   default Rails spec generators should not use the monkey patched
>   version of `describe`.
>
> Always using only the non-monkey patched `RSpec.describe`, instead of
>   inspecting the configuration, has the benefits of:
>
> - not requiring RSpec to be loaded when the generators are run by Rails
> - not introducing extra logic and state to handle the different states
> - Resolve #1048

https://github.com/rspec/rspec-rails/commit/ca0d249858903949052e06884e8e7f9d596cdc79